# how to select random unique records on each execution of the SQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have a table "masterurls" it has morethan 1 million records. I want to fetch random records each time the query executed. It should not have any of the records that were fetched in previous executions. I'm already have this query:

`SELECT m.url FROM masterurls ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 200`

The problem is the above query returns only first 200 hundred records and randomizes it each time.

Comment: `m` is not defined. and which programming language???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can pass a seed parameter to the `RAND()` function, you can "paginate" the random results by generating a seed before the first page.

Sample code:
For the first page (varies by language):

```
int seed = Math.abs(new Random().nextInt());
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT url FROM masterurls ORDER BY RAND({seed}) LIMIT 200;
```

Store the seed somewhere (for web-based applications you can use a url parameter or session).
For the next pages:

```
SELECT url FROM masterurls ORDER BY RAND({seed}) LIMIT 200 * {pageNumber}, 200;
```

Note: Sorting by `RAND()` is a heavy operation, you might be better off storing a indexed column with the Hash Code of the url, then using a module-based or other random functions.

Comment: Thank you! the random offset idea in limit solved my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

How are you going to know if the url is already accessed before. My best suggestion would be setting a flag to know this in the table. Add a field like view in the table which will accept two values 1 or 0, 1 for already accessed and 0 for not accessed. Then you could use

```
SELECT m.url FROM masterurls m WHERE view='1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 200;
```

Comment: How would he access the 2nd set of rows **while updating them to `view = 1`**? I would suggest - based on this answer, which will only work with a single viewer at a time - having the column values 0 1 or 2, 0 = now viewed. 1 = view now and 2 = viewed. run a `UPDATE SET view=1 WHERE view = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 200`, then select those 200 rows (`SELECT WHERE view = 1`) and finally perform a `UPDATE SET view = 2 WHERE view = 1`.

Comment: I just wrote the query to retrieve the records and not to update. I was thinking of update the records from the webpage or form. So, I asked which programming language, because i dont know to do this from SQL only.