# How to query 10 random unique records in mysql database?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to select random unique records on each execution of the SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966154/how-to-select-random-unique-records-on-each-execution-of-the-sql-query)

I have database of that structure:

```
id int
image_name varchar(200)
category_id int
```

There are about 200 records, id is unique, and there are about 20 categories, and my iamges are categorized between them.

Could you help me to get a query, which will give me 10 records with UNIQUE category_ids?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select DISTINCT(category),id,image_name FROM images 
  WHERE id=
    (FLOOR(RAND() * 
           (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM images )
          )
    );
```

Comment: Nice work, but is it possible that the IDs won't always match up with the count?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(category),id,image_name FROM images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT category_id,id,image_name FROM images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```